# Regular expression pattern to match UUID with optional parenthesis

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015

I've found a PCRE Pattern to match a UUID with optional parenthesis:

```
^(\{)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(?(1)\}|$)
```

This pattern matches:

```
{39E83341-4D11-4826-9020-847DDDE11C1B}
39E83341-4D11-4826-9020-847DDDE11C1B
```

but doesn't match:

```
{39E83341-4D11-4826-9020-847DDDE11C1B
39E83341-4D11-4826-9020-847DDDE11C1B}
```

which is exactly what I want.

It seems, this pattern isn't supported by the ECMAScript grammar (I'm using Visual Studio 2015).

Is there a way to achieve the same with ECMA? or one of the other grammar supported by `std::regex`?

Thx in advance!
Fred

Comment: So, you are using `std::regex`? No, conditonals are not supported there.

Comment: well, that's what I saw. But is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Only with alternation. [`^(?:\{[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\}|[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12})$`](https://regex101.com/r/tO5hZ4/2). Is it OK with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without having to spell out the alternatives by using two [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?![^{}]*\})(?:(?=.*\})\{)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\}?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Start of string
(?![^{}]*\})  # Assert that no closing } occurs before an opening one.
(?:           # Match...
 (?=.*\})     # if a closing } follows later...
 \{           # an opening {
)?            # optionally.
[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}
\}?           # Match an optional }
$             # at the end of the string.
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qS9kB2/1).

Answer (score 2):

Since `std::regex` does not support conditional constructs, an *alternation group* can be used to match the strings with `{...}` and without them:

```
^(?:\{[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\}|[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12})$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO5hZ4/2)

The pattern will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:`  - starting the alternation group

  - `\{` - a `{`
  - `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}` - UUID string
  - `\}`  - a closing `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?‌​:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}` - UUID string
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Note that (non-quantified) alternation groups are much less resource-consuming than lookaheads.

Comment: well that was the only solution I've found, but I thought, it's not so "pretty", and the performance would be worse.

Comment: Longer patterns - if written in a linear way (all subsequent subpatterns cannot match the same text at the same location) - are much better than shorter ones. Maybe performance is not something you should worry about if you know your input is not that long, is "predictable".